Hatching algorithm for binary bitmap
I try to develop an hatching algorithm, which can create an hatching based on a binary bitmap.
The result should look like in the example image:

Input data is a binary 2D array (bitmap)
For each line from x1,y1 to x2,y2 do:
Find the intersection segments, where the bitmap is black (==0)
Create as output a list of line segments


I've been working on some basic ideas based on Bresenham's line algorithm where I try to find all the intersections with the X and Y grids. Find the corresponding "pixels" in the bitmap and decide whether to start or continue a line.But with no solution so far

No, Bresenham algo is not a good choice here. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65753934/844416
